# Calculating ratio of consecutive values in dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I have a dataframe with 5 second intraday data of a stock. The dataframe exists of a column for the date, one for the time and one for the price at that moment.
I want to make a new column in which it calculates the ratio of two consecutive price values.
I tried it with a for loop, which works but is really slow.

```
data["ratio"]<- 0
i<-2
for(i in 2:nrow(data))
{
  if(is.na(data$price[i])== TRUE){
    data$ratio[i] <- 0
  } else {
    data$ratio[i] <- ((data$price[i] / data$price[i-1]) - 1) 
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a faster option, since my dataset contains more than 500.000 rows.
I was already trying something with ddply:

```
data["ratio"]<- 0
fun <- function(x){
  data$ratio <- ((data$price/lag(data$price, -1))-1)
}
ddply(data, .(data), fun)
```

and mutate:

```
data<- mutate(data, (ratio =((price/lag(price))-1)))
```

but both don't work and I don't know how to solve it...
Hopefully somebody can help me with this!

Comment: That's a nice attempt there, but I'm afraid it will be hard to help you if you won't share a small part of your data and your desired output too

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `lag` function to shift the your data by one row and then take the ratio of the original data to the shifted data. This is vectorized, so you don't need a for loop, and it should be much faster. Also, the number of lag units in the `lag` function has to be positive, which may be causing an error when you run your code.

```
# Create some fake data
set.seed(5)  # For reproducibility
dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(10))

dat$ratio = dat$x/lag(dat$x,1)

dat
             x       ratio
1  -0.84085548          NA
2   1.38435934 -1.64637013
3  -1.25549186 -0.90691183
4   0.07014277 -0.05586875
5   1.71144087 24.39939227
6  -0.60290798 -0.35228093
7  -0.47216639  0.78314834
8  -0.63537131  1.34565131
9  -0.28577363  0.44977422
10  0.13810822 -0.48327840
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop in R can be extremely slow. Try to avoid it if you can.

```
datalen=length(data$price)

data$ratio[2:datalen]=data$price[1:datalen-1]/data$price[2:datalen]
```

You don't need to do the is.NA check, you will get NA in the result either the numerator or the denominator is NA.